# Read structure in files python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to populate a txt with the structure in certain directory, i read the files in the directory:

```
os.listdir(r)
```

But if one item is a directory i need to search into it, any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).  It will recursively traverse paths.  ex:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    ...
```